# How to remove object without getting index in angular 2

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to delete an object without getting index of object . In object i have following data i.e.,

```
{
  "id" : 1,
  "address": "abc ghsddsj",
  "phone" : "123467891"
},
{
  "id" : 2,
  "address": "abdffddfgc ghsddsj",
  "phone" : "7864545645"
}
```

// and here is my code to remove object

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
@Injectable()
export class AppService{
    addressList : any[] = [];
    newAddress: any;
    constructor ( public _router:Router){ }
    updateData(){
        this.addressList.push(this.newAddress);
    }
    getData(){
        return this.addressList;
    }
    deleteAddress(id:any){
        //let index = this.addressList.indexOf(address);
        //this.addressList.splice(index,1);
        for( let address of this.addressList ){
            if( address.id == id ){
              // expression code will be here
            } 
        }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter. Something like this:

```
this.addresList = this.addresList.filter(address => (address.id !== id));
```

Comment: Hi Bart thanks for giving an answer but it doesn't work yet.

Comment: Perhaps the problem is also you have id "1" twice. Oh and you should replace the for loop with this line. :)